# Is the yellow dot on iPhone camera icon itself active or just design?

Tags: iphone, icon, camera

Apple lets iPhone users know that the camera and/or microphone are in use by displaying an orange or green dot in the status bar, upper right. But there is also a yellow dot on the icon itself. Is the icon dot just a design feature? Searching the web always redirects to explanations of the status bar dot.

[image: screenshot of iPhone camera icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The camera app icon is a static image that has had an orange dot in the corner since iOS 7. It is not dynamic and never changes; it does not indicate microphone usage, only the status bar dot does.